# Get the product object from sku and update the price in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, object, methods, woocommerce

How can I update a product by product_id in my functions file?

I tried using the below code but to no success:

```
$_pf = new WC_Product_Factory();  
$product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku );
$_product = $_pf->get_product($product_id);
$_product->set_price('225');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since WooCommerce 3, `new WC_Product_Factory()` with `get_product()` method is deprecated and replaced simply by the function `wc_get_product()`.

To update price, you have to update the price and the regular price *(or the price and the sale price)*...

Also the `save()` method is necessary to grab the data at the end.

So to get the `WC_Product` Object **from an existing product SKU** and to use on it any available method, do the following:

```
$new_price   = '225'; // New price
$_product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku );

if ( $_product_id > 0 ) {
    // Get an instance of the WC_Product Object
    $_product = wc_get_product( $_product_id );

    $_product->set_regular_price($new_price); // Set the regular price
    $_product->set_price($new_price); // Set the price
    $_product->save(); // Save to database and sync
} else {
    // Display an error (invalid Sku
    printf('Invalid sku "%s"… Can not update price.', $sku);
}
```

Tested and works.