# Creating a WooCommerce Order programmatically for a subscription product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-subscriptions

With woocommerce I am using WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin. I have created a function that can create an order based on the product SKU using `wc_get_product_id_by_sku()` function, from a Subscription product.

This is my function at the moment:

```
function create_new_order() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $address = array(
        'first_name' => 'Zakup',
        'last_name'  => 'Sklepowy',
        'email'      => 'test@test.pl',
        'phone'      => '123',
        'address_1'  => 'ul. Przykladowa 1',
        'address_2'  => 'm. 2',
        'city'       => 'Wroclaw',
        'postcode'   => '50-123',
    );


    $order = wc_create_order();

    $product = new WC_Product( wc_get_product_id_by_sku( 'wpoh-prof-webshop' ) );
    $order->add_product( $product, 1 );
    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );

    // Set payment gateway
    $payment_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->payment_gateways();
    $order->set_payment_method( $payment_gateways['cod'] );

    // Calculate totals
    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->update_status( 'completed', 'In Store ', true );
}
```

With this line:

```
$product = new WC_Product (wc_get_product_id_by_sku ('wpoh-prof-webshop'));
```

I pick up the product to be placed with the order. I have hardcoded the customer billing address in this function as its's required.

When I run the function, an empty order is created that does not have any product or address attached to it.

order created without personal information or product:

[image: order created without personal information or product]

Can someone help me and tell me where it goes wrong?

Comment: Thats what i mean hahaha, what i meant was when you are creating a order you sending a variable product with it.

Comment: First of all what I am trying to do at the moment is sku wpoh-prof-webshop already a selected variable product. When loading this function, he must create an order. As soon as he creates the order, the function must see which sku to include in the order + the address details. At the moment when I load the function, it creates an order that is empty without address data and without product.

Comment: If you are reading the code you know what it means. wpoh-prof-webshop is the SKU of the product im searching on $product = new WC_Product( wc_get_product_id_by_sku( 'wpoh-prof-webshop' ) );

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i changed the post can you check it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get one of the following subscription product objects:

- `WC_Product_Subscription` *(a `subscription` product type, a simple subscription)*,
- `WC_Product_Variable_Subscription` *(a `variable-subscription` product type)*,
- `WC_Product_Subscription_Variation` *(a `subscription_variation` product type)*.

You can **not** use `new WC_Product()` as it will **throw an error**.

**Instead you should use [`wc_get_product()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_product.html#46-65) function.**

Now `global $woocommerce;` is not required and doesn't do anything.

> **SKU: Get the product object from a product ID using `wc_get_product_id_by_sku()` function:**
>
> The SKU should always be from a simple subscription or a variation subscription, but **never** from a variable subscription product…

Try the following lightly modified function:

```
function create_new_order() {
    $sku = 'wpoh-prof-webshop';
    $address = array(
        'first_name' => 'Zakup',
        'last_name'  => 'Sklepowy',
        'email'      => 'test@test.pl',
        'phone'      => '123',
        'address_1'  => 'ul. Przykladowa 1',
        'address_2'  => 'm. 2',
        'city'       => 'Wroclaw',
        'postcode'   => '50-123',
    );

    $order = wc_create_order(); // Create a WC_Order object and save it.

    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' ); // Set customer billing adress
    
    $product = wc_get_product( wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku ) );
    $order->add_product( $product, 1 ); // Add an order line item
    
    // Set payment gateway
    $payment_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->payment_gateways();
    $order->set_payment_method( $payment_gateways['cod'] );
    
    $order->calculate_totals(); // Update order taxes and totals
    $order->update_status( 'completed', 'In Store ', true ); // Set order status and save
}
```

Tested and works.

Related answer: [Get the product object from sku and update the price in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56353114/get-the-product-object-from-sku-and-update-the-price-in-woocommerce/56356502#56356502)

Comment: Where do i need to add this? WC_Product_Subscription (a subscription product type, a simple subscription),
WC_Product_Variable_Subscription (a variable-subscription product type),
WC_Product_Subscription_Variation (a subscription_variation product type). if i want it to be a subscription its working as a normal order atm

Comment: @MaartendeWolf This answer code is based on yours and it solve the issue of empty order (what you asked): `wc_get_product()` works for any product type even for subscription products types. What makes the product type with `wc_get_product()` is the product id that you set in it. So if the SKU is from a simple subscription product, you will get the WC_Product_Subscription object or if it's from a subscription variation, you will get a WC_Product_Variable_Subscription Object…

Comment: @MaartendeWolf To get an order for a renew subscription, you have **to set in the order the parent order ID using `set_parent_id()`** (so the order ID from the1st initial order for the subscription). But this is another question…

Answer (score 0):

Maarten de Wolf, you can add it to separate .php file, but it needs to be accepted by adding:

`require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');`

before the script (it loads ex. session info - that you're logged in as admin).

Comment: Thanks im now trying to create a renew subscription of my order. Maybe you can help me out with that. the order is created when loading the function. But it wont renew somehow